# Javascript and CSS if statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im very new to programming and im trying to make a code which will cause an image to only appear if the ctrl key is not being pressed.

```
<script language=JavaScript>

document.onkeydown = checkKey;
var Showimg = False;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '17') {
      alert('test');
      Showimg = True;
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the code ive currently got.  I have code in another division below which has the code for the image in.

I'm very new to CSS and javascript, and basically most coding in general, so im not sure if its possible to get an image to no longer show if the ctrl key is pressed, as "if" statements dont seem to work outside the script, but the image code wont work inside the script.

This may not be detailed enough, sorry.

Comment: Change `False` and `True` to `false` and `true`.

Comment: Add quotes in this part: `language="javascript">`.

Comment: Do you want the `ctrl` key to be in addition to it? If you are looking to only act on keypresses where the key is held down, you could check out the `ctrlKey` property on the `KeyboardEvent`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey Great place to start.

Comment: not `<script language=JavaScript>` but `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: In html5, `language` is deprecated, and `type` is optional.  You can just use `<script>`.

Comment: @Sushanth-- using strict comparisons because it's "faster" is nonsense. We use it because we want to prevent errors and/or want to compare types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have the event part down to determine when the ctrl key is pressed. What you need now (apart from some syntax issues others have pointed out) is to use javascript to hide the image. First you'll want a way to identify it, so for example you can add an id of img (or whatever).

```
<img id="img">
```

Then you can use js to target this and change the display property within your if statement.

```
document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'none';
```

This code will a) find the image, and b) change the display to not be shown.

Comment: In case the page has relative layout, `element.style.display = "none"` might cause changes in the positioning of other elements. In such case it is probably preferred to use `element.style.visibility = "hidden"`.

Comment: @remdevtec Depends on your interpretation of 'not shown' :) Fair point though

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e);
    if (e.keyCode === 17) {
      document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function show() {
    document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'block';
}
```

make the body like this

`<body onkeydown="checkKey()" onkeyup="show()">`

and for the image, you could make it like this

`<img src="test.jpg" id="image">`